# Using c++ rest SDK to make a GET request including headers / body

Tags: c++, api, rest, visual-c++, casablanca

How do I make an http GET request with headers and possibly a body using c++ rest SDK?
I'm able to make a GET request without headers / body as follows:

```
web::http::client::http_client client(U("https://host.com"));
pplx::task<http_response> response = client.request(methods::GET, U("/URL/"));
response.then(...)......
```

and a POST request works with headers and json body like this:

```
web::json::value body = web::json::value::object();
web::http::client::http_client client(U("Full URL"));
http_request req(methods::POST);
req.headers().add(U("..."), U("..."));
req.headers().add(U("..."), ...);
//construct body here
req.set_body(body);
auto response = client.request(req).then(...)......
```

This also works. But everytime I try a GET request and add the headers / body, I get an error with the reponse.

At first I thought it would just be a matter of using the POST method and changing methods::POST to methods::GET but this does not work.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: When just trying to add headers, this is what I originally thought would work:

```
web::http::client::http_client client(U("Full URL"));
http_request req(methods::GET);
req.headers().add(U("..."), U("..."));
req.headers().add(U("..."), ...);
auto response = client.request(req).then(...)......
```

Comment: It is unclear how it makes sense to have body/payload in a GET request? Perhaps such request is rejected.

Comment: GET requests can't have bodies, its not allowed by the HTTP standard https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1

Comment: In that case, it appears the GET request requires just headers and no body. How would it be done with headers?

Comment: Please show a [mre], "doesn't work" isn't a great description of your problem. What i exactly is happening, what's the error message?